# Disable/Enable mouse wheel scroll for a panel

Tags: c#, winforms, scroll, mousewheel

In my WinForm there a is Panel with some grids, grids have scroll bar too. I wanted to scroll each grid using mouse wheel and scroll the panel using Shift+scroll.
Tried this:

```
private void sitePnlGrid_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
                if (Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Shift)
                   this.sitePnlGrid.DisableScroll = false;
                else
                   this.sitePnlGrid.DisableScroll = true;
    }
```

And this:

```
public class CustomScrollPanel : Panel
    {
        public bool DisableScroll { get; set; }
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            if (m.Msg == 0x20a && DisableScroll==true) return; 
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
    }
```

Set `this.sitePnlGrid.DisableScroll = false;` in Initialization.

This is disabling the scroll but not enabling it back. I mean: If I do Shift+scroll first, scroll works on panel. Just do Scroll, it is disabling the panel scroll so, I can scroll the grid. But if I do Shift+scroll again then scroll in panel is not working.

How to enable the panel scroll back once it is disabled?

Answer (score 0):

**[EDIT] Ok, I leave my code here. But the fact is : it is a standard behavior that pressing the shift key during a mouse scroll will have effect on the parent panel. There is nothing more to do.**

Here something that should work.

The lack is that you have to do this modification for all the types of components that you should want to put in your panel.

```
class MyDataGridView : DataGridView
{
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        // If the message is for this component, is about mouse wheel
        // and if the shift key is pressed,
        // we transmit it to the parent control.
        // Otherwise, we handle it normally.
        if ((m.HWnd == Handle) && (m.Msg == WM_MOUSEWHEEL) && (ModifierKeys == Keys.Shift))
        {
            PostMessage(Parent.Handle, m.Msg, m.WParam, m.LParam);
        }
        else
        {
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
    }

    #region User32.dll
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    private const int WM_MOUSEWHEEL = 0x020A;
    #endregion
}
```